# How do get a timestamp on an ASP.NET MVC App

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, kendo-grid

On web apps,  you commonly see something like "Last Logged In: 3 hours 42 minutes ago".   What is the best way to go about doing this.?  Use strings or Dates?  Also,  i'm bringing that timestamp back into a Kendo MVC Grid.  The column looks as such.

```
columns.Bound(c => c.LastStatusDateDiff).Title("Updated");
```

My Linq code looks as such

```
select new ATSReDto
                {
                    CreatedDate = atsr.CreatedDt,
                    Desciption = atsr.Description,
                    LastStatusDateDiff = laststatus.CreatedDt - DateTime.Now    
// get date difference between now "DateTime.Now" and 
// date/time pulled from SQL Server to display in Grid
                };
```

Any suggestions greatly appreciated

Comment: Really hard to beat https://momentjs.com/ not sure how easy it is to implement with kendo-grid, but highly recommended.  Easy to support regional times as well.

Comment: Do you have to support multiple time zones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is Kendo UI related, you could add a read-only property in the ViewModel class.

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public DateTime LastStatus { get; set; }

    public string LastStatusText
    {
        get
        {
            var span = DateTime.Now - LastStatus;
            return string.Format("Last Logged in : {0} days  {1} hours {2} minutes ago",
                span.Days, span.Hours, span.Minutes);
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
columns.Bound(c => c.LastStatusText).Title("Updated");
```

Comment: very good answer Win.  Just what i was looking for.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

use [`TimeSpan`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan(v=vs.110).aspx)

`TimeSpan diff = Math.Abs(dateTime1 - dateTime2);`

> Formatting a TimeSpan Value
>
> A TimeSpan value can be represented as [-]d.hh:mm:ss.ff, where the optional minus sign indicates a negative time interval, the d component is days, hh is hours as measured on a 24-hour clock, mm is minutes, ss is seconds, and ff is fractions of a second. That is, a time interval consists of a positive or negative number of days without a time of day, or a number of days with a time of day, or only a time of day.
>
> The TimeSpan.ToString(String) overload lets you specify a format string that defines the string representation of the time interval. The TimeSpan.ToString(String, IFormatProvider) overload lets you specify a format string and the culture whose formatting conventions are used to create the string representation of the time interval. TimeSpan supports both standard and custom format strings. (For more information, see [Standard TimeSpan Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372286(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Custom TimeSpan Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287(v=vs.110).aspx).) However, only standard format strings are culture-sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with Kendo, but jQuery offers a plugin called TimeAgo for this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("time.timeago").timeago();
});
```

Docs: http://timeago.yarp.com/ Plugin: https://plugins.jquery.com/timeago/

**Edit**

Apparently, you can markup your razor controller using Kendo like this:

```
<abbr class="timeago" title="@Model.LastActivityDateString">@Model.LastActivityDateString</abbr>
```

After setting it in your model:

```
LastActivityDateString=DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("o");
```

Note: You are just returning the date of the event not getting the difference as your code shows.

And your would initialize with Javascript like this:

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".timeago").timeago();
});
```